# Created a function with roots at primes and only primes, are there useful applications?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions, prime-numbers

Here's the function I created (I have a very long proof too):
$$(-1)^{\dfrac{4\Gamma(
(x-1)(1-(\lceil x\rceil-\lfloor x\rfloor)+1)
)+4}{(x-1)(1-(\lceil x\rceil-\lfloor x\rfloor))+1}}-1,\quad x>1$$
Is there any use for this? As far as I know it's the first of its kind. [Wolfram Alpha link.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B(((-1)%5E((4gamma(((x-1)*(1-(ceiling(x)-floor(x)))%2B1))%2B4)%2F((x-1)*(1-(ceiling(x)-floor(x)))%2B1)))-1),%20%7Bx,%202,%2020%7D%5D)

Comment: @YuriyS He has already proven it is sufficient for every prime.

Comment: Also, your function $f(x)$, although very nice, is similar to the recurrence relation, $$a_n = \{a_{n-1} + \gcd(n, a_{n - 1}) : a_1 = 7\}$$ for which $a_n - a_{n-1} = \gcd(n, a_{n-1})$ equates to $1$ if not prime.

Comment: I guess you should state it as:

$$(-1)^{k(x)}-1$$

Where:

$$k(x)=\dfrac{4\Gamma(
(x-1)(1-(\lceil x\rceil-\lfloor x\rfloor)+1)
)+4}{(x-1)(1-(\lceil x\rceil-\lfloor x\rfloor))+1}$$

Or:

$$(-1)^{\tiny \dfrac{4\Gamma(
(x-1)(1-(\lceil x\rceil-\lfloor x\rfloor)+1)
)+4}{(x-1)(1-(\lceil x\rceil-\lfloor x\rfloor))+1}} -1 $$

It gets a little bit more readable. I for one spent a lot of time trying to understand why there were floating a $"(-1)"$ and a floating $-1$.

Comment: It might be worth noting that slightly less trivially, one can define the function $\prod_p (1-\frac zp)e^{z/p}$, where the product is over all primes; by the [Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) this function is entire and has zeros at the primes and nowhere else. Alternately, if one wants to include $-2, -3, -5, \ldots$ as primes, then the product $\prod_p \left(1-(\frac zp)^2\right)$ (here the product is over the positive primes, but by construction the function will have zeros at their negatives as well) will also do the trick.

Comment: This seems very cool, and I think the existing answers don't do it enough justice.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your function simplifies to
$$(-1)^{4((x-1)!+1)/x}-1$$
and is just a restatement of Wilson's theorem: $(n-1)!\equiv-1\bmod n$ iff $n$ is prime.

If $x$ is prime, $((x-1)!+1)/x=k$ is an integer and $(-1)^{4k}-1$ evaluates to zero. If $x$ is composite and $\ge6$, $k=n+\frac1x$ where $n$ is an integer, so $(-1)^{4k}-1$ does not evaluate to zero. The function evaluated at $x=4$ gives $k=7/4$, which makes $(-1)^{4k}-1=-2\ne0$.

Comment: Hello, could you please clarify the step that says k = n + 1/x if x is composite gte 6?

Comment: @Hamsterrific Wilson's theorem also says that if $n$ is composite and greater than 6, $(n-1)!\equiv0\bmod n$. Then $k=((x-1)!+1)/x=(x-1)!/x+1/x$, and $(x-1)!/x$ is an integer by the previous argument.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that Wilson's Theorem had this "second part". Thanks

Comment: @ParclyTaxel thanks! It seems the function only works if input is guaranteed to be an integer. Otherwise, this will have roots between the integers, so it's not a complete simplification of mine because of the removal of the floor and ceiling, but it still explains what's going on to show that this isn't really 'new'. Thanks!

Comment: What does negative 1 to the power of a non-integer mean?

Comment: @goblin A complex number.

Comment: But what is the definition? I wasn't aware this was possible ...

Comment: @goblin We treat $-1=e^{i\pi}$; all the properties of exponentiating it with any real power follow.

Answer (score 20):

> As far as I know it's the first of its kind.

It is certainly not. The function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } x \text{ is prime}\\ 1& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

is also a function for which $f(x)=0$ if and only if $x$ is prime.

Also, replacing $4$ with $2$ seems to maintain the property.

Comment: That is formally correct, but I wonder if it is the answer which Albert is looking for, as his expression is more or less "elementary". – (Ask a mathematician “Can you tell me what time it is?” – Answer: “Yes.”)

Comment: @MartinR That was a very good comparison haha